# Como lanzar el home en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

si estoy en mi aplicación y envió al usuario a su configuración con esto.

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Pero como puedo enviar al usuario al home de su teléfono, no retornarlo a la aplicación.

Ya que para retornarlo a la aplicación es con esto

```
Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent(context,Home.class);
LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres simular que el usuario ha pulsado "Home" y que tu app quede oculta pero funcionando, puedes hacer algo así:

```
public static void pulsarBotonHome(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si al decir "home del telefono" te refieres al desktop, si te encuentras en el Activity principal, simplemente finaliza después de realizar el intent con un `finish()`

Ejemplo:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS), 0);
finish();
```